# Spark 3.0.0 stopped supporting multiple contexts

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to upgrade to Spark 3.0.0 (Java 11)

The code that **used to work** in Spark 2.4.6, Scala 2.11 now fails with the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).The currently running SparkContext was created at:
```

My code goes like this

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName(sparkParams.get("appName"))
        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
        .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

    //fails here!
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
```

Am I missing something? What should I do to make this work?

Comment: why do you need multiple context? one context is enough.

Comment: Got it to work by changing the code to only use one Spark context.